# How do i find an integer at position x in a linked list?

Tags: c#

```
if (choice == 1)
            {   for (int x = 1; x <= Small.Count()-1;x++)
            {
                Number min = (Number)Small[x-1]; // i know this how you do it for an array list
                int minpos = x - 1;
```

Number is the value in the list i want to find and small is the list

Comment: What type is small of?

Comment: public SinglyLinkedList Small;

Comment: So you implemented the list on your own? Do the logic there, e.g. you could overload the [] operator. If you want us to help you we need more information, we cannot guess your project content. Just edit your question appropriately.

Comment: Is this a some kind of Algorithm homework or something? it depends on how you build the SinglyLinkedList. If it is build with a list and not an array, you can't doe Small[x]

Comment: Im trying to use selectionSort with a singlylinked list.

Comment: Ok, you want to sort the list using selectionSort, but first you have to get the list working^^

Answer (score 1):

To get the nth element in a singly linked list (asuming `SinglyLinkedList` contains the Next variable)

```
public SinglyLinkedList ElementAt(int position)
{
    SinglyLinkedList node = Head;
    int counter = 0;
    while (node != null && counter++ != position)
    {
        node = node.Next;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Assuming singly linked list: 37 -> 29 -> 45 -> 90 -> 10 -> 4 -> 21 -> 7

```
list.ElementAt(0)     // Output: 37
list.ElementAt(5)     // Output: 4
list.ElementAt(20)    // Output: null
```